# Payflow Advanced: Secure token?

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I'm trying to integrate PayPal Payflow Advanced into my site, and I'm so confused...  I've enabled secure tokens in the management interface, but I'm not clear on whether that's generated from their side or mine?

I've never done this before and really, the developer guides and sdks and even the forum posts feel extremely elusive...  I'm just not sure about the process...

It seems as though I can embed an iframe and then they handle the rest, but one of the parameters is SECURETOKEN and SECURETOKENID.  I don't know where I get those values from?  I don't see it anywhere in any of the paypal settings for my account, so I think it might be something I need to generate?  But, if it is, then I don't know exactly what kind of token I should send?  Just any old random string?

Sorry... But, I'm really unclear on this, despite having googled and gone through the paypal documentation... Plus, I think my PMDD is acting up, so I'm hoping to get a solution before I take this computer and huff it out the window...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post now, but the answer is that you have to perform a token request using server-side code. There is an PHP example of a secure token request in this post:

https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/new-payflow-gateway-tutorial

This was for a PayFlow Pro integration. Also see chapter 2 of https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf for the syntax of the request. You may need to look into the specifics of what is required in the token request for your product.

Comment: PayFlow Pro works very differently from Payflow Advanced.  The documentation for the latter seems to be scarce.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already, try looking here under the section “PayPal Payments Advanced and PayPal Payments Pro (Payflow Pro/Link)”

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/nates-blog-home-page

and

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/pp_integrations_preston/testing-paypal-payflow-gateway

Thanks

Comment: The links in this post are dead.